# SugarCRM relationship to get contacts from active opportunities

Tags: java, rest, sugarcrm

I am working on sugarCRM, I need to get all the contacts from active opportunities. I can relate  the contacts with Opportunities for single record using the below url

```
https://xxxxxxxx.trial.sugarcrm.eu/rest/v10/Opportunities/5ae1907a-9408-178f-87d6-523cc7d679b6/link/contacts
```

But I have to get he contacts details for all  opportunities which is active.
Can Anyone please help me....
Thanks in advance

Comment: If answers help you plz upvote and accept answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are going right , The url provide by:

```
https://xxxxxxxx.trial.sugarcrm.eu/rest/v10/Opportunities/5ae1907a-9408-178f-87d6-523cc7d679b6/link/contacts
```

It will give all record related to that Opportunities.

**But you want All contacts of active Opportunities**

1. First you need to hit API for Opportunities which is active :

   https://xxxxxxxx.trial.sugarcrm.eu/rest/v10/Opportunities/filter[0][status][$in][]=active

Like this you can apply filter.

[For more help check this link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Integration/Web_Services/v10/Examples/Bash/How_to_Filter_a_List_of_Records/)

2.Now after that you get array on Opportunities , so will use loop get get **Opportunities id**  and hit your URL.

```
https://xxxxxxxx.trial.sugarcrm.eu/rest/v10/Opportunities/5ae1907a-9408-178f-87d6-523cc7d679b6/link/contacts
```

You  can make Dynamic according to your need.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you Amitesh

Comment: how can I  achieve this API v4

Comment: This API are available in sugar , when you use sugar it will show  which api is hitting in firebug in chrome. Or read sugarcrm documents.

Comment: yes I went through the API documentation of API V4 but I have roadblock please look into the question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342365/sugarcrc-access-denied-number-40) and help me