# SugarCRM Access denied number 40

Tags: java, sugarcrm

I am trying to get all contacts from the active opportunities below is my request of SugarCRM API v4

```
{
   "session":"btcskfetq7sqshio3uv568d8c1",
   "module_name":"Contacts",
   "query":"contacts.id IN (
       SELECT opportunities_contacts.contact_id 
       FROM opportunities_contacts 
       JOIN opportunities 
       ON opportunities_contacts.opportunity_id = opportunities.id 
       WHERE opportunities.sales_stage 
       NOT IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost'))",
   "order_by":"",
   "offset":0,
   "select_fields":[
       "first_name",
       "last_name",
       "title",
       "phone_home",
       "phone_work",
       "status",
       "email"
   ],
  "link_name_to_fields_array":null,
  "max_results":0,
  "deleted":0,
  "favorites":false
}
```

my **query** is working fine in mysql workbench in sugarCRM database but the API response is:

`{"name":"Access Denied","number":40,"description":"You do not have access"}`

Can you help?

Comment: Looks like an authentication issue.  Do any simpler requests work?  I think you need to hash your password with MD5 if you haven't done that.

Comment: I did password hashing using MD5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Achive this you to write Your own end point in suagrcrm .

```
<?php
class AtRiskApi extends SugarApi
{
    // This function is only called whenever the rest service cache file is deleted.
    // This shoud return an array of arrays that define how different paths map to different functions
    public function registerApiRest() {
        return array(
            'getAtRisk' => array(
                // What type of HTTP request to match against, we support GET/PUT/POST/DELETE
                'reqType' => 'GET',
                // This is the path you are hoping to match, it also accepts wildcards of ? and <module>
                'path' => array('Accounts', 'at_risk'),
                // These take elements from the path and use them to populate $args
                'pathVars' => array('', ''),
                // This is the method name in this class that the url maps to
                'method' => 'getAtRisk',
                // The shortHelp is vital, without it you will not see your endpoint in the /help
                'shortHelp' => 'Lists at risk accounts in the system',
                // The longHelp points to an HTML file and will be there on /help for people to expand and show
                'longHelp' => '',
            ),
        );
    }

    function getAtRisk($api, $args)
    {
        // Start off with something simple so we can verify the endpoint is registered.
        return 'burgers';
    }
}
```

For More Details Read this :

[Read me ...](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/03/10/sugarcrm-cookbook-adding-a-rest-endpoint-2/)

Comment: Thanks Amitesh I will look into this.

Comment: This is for the v10 API but the question was in regards to v4.

Comment: you have to use V10 this latest.I think this will also same for v4.

Comment: I am separately implementing api v4 and V10 I can able to achieve this in v10 but not in v4

Comment: you have to use V10 if you are using latest version of sugarcrm

Comment: yes, but one of our client using older version of the CRM that needs V4.1 API

Comment: then for that you have check document for v4.1